# 2 factor authentication on Watson Assistant and Watson Discovery?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation, watson-discovery

Is there any way to enable 2 factor authentication on Watson Assistant and Watson Discovery? I am thinking in securing it with VPN if no other means are available.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2018/05/ibm-cloud-platform-now-adds-support-multi-factor-authentication/

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Watson, however if it's web-based, you can put it behind an Apache proxy server, and use the 2FA plugin: https://github.com/archiecobbs/mod-authn-otp.

It uses one-time codes produced by apps such as [Google Authenticator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2&hl=en_US).